# Command required to grep only latest unique MSISDN from data

Tags: linux

I have one data in which there are 5 fields and all are comma separated. There are two main field infact field 1 is Date in YYYYMMDD format and second field contains MSISDN 10 digits. The file has around 120 million numbers in which some numbers are duplicates, triplicates but the date is differs in that case.

I need only unique MSISDN but the date should be the latest one.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far (By the way, 12 crore is 120 million. It might help some readers)

Comment: Some sample lines of data would be useful.  I suspect the entire problem can be solved with `sort`, `cut`, and `uniq`

Comment: Below is the format of data.                 20150202,9305027876,3142,180,181
20150202,7408393141,3142,180,230
20150202,7439145410,3147,182,181
20150202,8653681103,3151,182,212
20150202,9279543620,3145,182,213
20150202,8342995876,4191,182,230
20150202,9854057888,3144,182,120
20150201,7894447232,3008,212,120
20150202,8014518074,3149,182,110
20150201,8797852093,3285,220,212
 and i am  just trying below command to fetch the output.. Please comment..   sort -t, -nr -k 1 sohan|sort -u -t, -k 2,2

Answer (score 0):

first of all, sort the file using:

```
sort filename.txt > filename.sort
```

second write a program to and parse the file line by line. At each line find msisdn and write that number to a map `map.put(msisdn,lunenumber)`. after this step, pars the file again and print lines that its line number are exists in the `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with `awk`? Perhaps a combination of `sort` and `awk` will do it for you. We assume that the file is unsorted.

Create a file called `crore.sh` and type this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

sort --field-separator=',' -rn -k 2,2 \
     -k 1,1 your-filename.txt \
     |
     awk -F',' '
BEGIN {
    line = 1;
    maxdate = "";
    id = -1;
}
{
    if (line == 1) {
        maxdate = $1;
        id = $2;

        # to print entire line, use this
        #print $0;

        # to print only date and id, use this
        print maxdate,"\t",id;
    }
    else {
        if ($2 != id) {
            maxdate = $1;
            id = $2;
            #print $0;
            print maxdate,"\t",id;
        }
    }
    line++;
}
'
```

Don't forget the last single quote. Change your-filename.txt with the file that contains your information. Then run,

```
$> bash crore.sh
```

My file had the following contents

```
20150101,1,test
20150401,2,test
20150101,1,test
20150701,2,test
20150401,1,test

Result after running the program:
20150701         2
20150401         1
```

Run with a smaller subset of your data to get a feel of runtime and whether the output is OK.

**Explanation**

- We `sort` the data by 2nd field and 1st field - both in reverse order
- We will get highest date for each ID first, followed by any other duplicate records for the ID
- With `awk`, we extract the first record and every record with a different ID that we come across

Hope this information helps.